# Java design - abstract class declaration example explanation

Tags: java, generics

I've encounter an abstract class with this declaration:

```
public abstract class AbstractSomeView<V extends SomeView<V, P>, P extends SomePresenter<V, P>> extends Composite implements SomeView<V, P> {
...
}
```

`V` and `P` are View and Presenter types.

Is there a simpler way to achieve what it achieves, a more intuitive design?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: I guess it depends on the reader if it is 'intuitive' or not. Are you looking for a more simple/readable way of notation?

Comment: Well, basically it's a thing of 2 things. Can't it be simplified? To me it seems like spaghetti, when it's some rules on 2 types of classes

Comment: @Petronella: the reason it's complicated is that it's not just "a thing of 2 things". It's "a thing of a type A that needs to know what type B is and a type B that needs to know what type B is". If you just had a View and a Presenter with no relation to each other it would be simpler.